# How to fix "error in module SensorManager during network initialization" in Castalia

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I've been trying to run valueReporting simulation using castalia. I've edited the ini file in ordre to add to a node 2 sensor devices ( weight and blood glucose). However i'm facing the following error running the simulation :

**Error in module (SensorManager) SN.node[0].SensorManager (id=10) during network initialization: Model error: 
[Sensor Device Manager]: The parameters of the sensor device manager are not initialized correctly in omnet.ini file..**

Here's a sample of the omnetpp.ini file. [omnetpp.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMdnY.jpg)

Does anybody have any idea why i'm having this error ? if so, how can i fix it ?

Thank you !

Comment: When you want to include an ini file or other text based file, it's better to paste it as code in the question rather than taking a screenshot and linking an image. Stackoverflow gives you a lot of nice formatting options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you searched for the error message `The parameters of the sensor device manager are not initialized correctly in omnet.ini file` in the code you would find it in `SensorManager.cc`.

You could then figure out that this error is triggered when any of 9 parameters do not match the number of sensor devices you have on the node. These are the 9 parameters:

```
SN.node[0].SensorManager.sensorTypes
SN.node[0].SensorManager.corrPhyProcess
SN.node[0].SensorManager.pwrConsumptionPerDevice
SN.node[0].SensorManager.maxSampleRates
SN.node[0].SensorManager.devicesBias
SN.node[0].SensorManager.devicesNoise
SN.node[0].SensorManager.devicesSensitivity
SN.node[0].SensorManager.devicesResolution
SN.node[0].SensorManager.devicesSaturation
```

You only define the first two correctly in your ini file. All the rest have the default values, which include only one sensor type, you need to include two values for each. You can look at SensorManager.ned to see what are the default values that these parameters take. You can then simply copy these values, or change them according to your needs.

For example `devicesNoise` default value is "0.1", so for two sensing devices it can be "0.1 0.1"

Comment: Yes indeed i figured it out, thank you. Now i'm facing another issue, when simulating the scenario i noticed that only one sensor is sampling data from one physical process ( sensor 0 from physical process 0 ), sensor 1 isn't getting any data from physical process 1. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: There is not enough info to speculate. You should ask a seperate *complete* question in this site.

Comment: Also, if you figure out how to answer your own question, it is recommended to actually answer it on this site.

Comment: @ Thanassis Okey, got it.